# Find entire number between # and space at variable places within a cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

How can I find an entire number between a "#" and a space when that combination could appear anywhere in a given cell?

Example cell contents:

"This is a #123 Test that I 45 like to run" 
"This is a #45 Test that I 98 like to run"

I need to return "123" from the first one and "45" from the second one.

Using Mid(), I can return the "1", but the problem is the number between # and space can vary in length, but there will generally be a #, number or numbers, then a space.

As a **secondary issue**, there may be scenarios where there is no "#", but I need to find the first numeric value in the cell and return them (i.e. "1", "34", "648").

Any advice on either of these challenges is greatly appreciated.

Comment: So basically you just want to find the first number in a cell, regardless of whether it's prepended by a # symbol?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work as well:

```
=MID(A11,(FIND("#",A11,1)+1),FIND(" ",A11,FIND("#",A11,1)+1)-FIND("#",A11,1))
```

works by looking for the hash and the following space... Not for the secondary question...

Comment: That worked great for my first scenario! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

This will return the first number in a string:

```
=--LEFT(MID(A1,AGGREGATE(15,6,FIND({1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0},A1),1),LEN(A1)),FIND(" ",MID(A1,AGGREGATE(15,6,FIND({1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0},A1),1),LEN(A1))))
```

[image]

AGGREGATE was introduced in 2010 Excel.  If you do not ahve that then you will need to use this array formula:

```
=--LEFT(MID(A1,MIN(IFERROR(FIND({1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0},A1),1E+99)),LEN(A1)),FIND(" ",MID(A1,MIN(IFERROR(FIND({1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0},A1),1E+99)),LEN(A1))))
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.  If done correctly then excel will put `{}` around the formula.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the response. I attempted your exact formula and the contents of A1 as you wrote them and I get #Name?. I'm sure its user error on my part but any ideas on what I might be doing wrong. I see how its worked flawlessly for you so I'm quite intrigued. Perhaps its because I'm in Excel 2007 (yeah, I know, I need to upgrade!). Thanks!

Comment: @Cherubim I have just tried Scott's solution (not in excel 2007) and it is working for both scenarios. Earliest excel I have is 2011 on a mac.

Comment: Thanks Solar Mike. I just looked up the Aggregate function and from what I'm finding it only works on 2010 and later versions. Guess I'm out of luck there until I upgrade.

Comment: @Cherubim sorry was away.  See edit for solution that will work with 2007

Answer (score 1):

Since you've put the excel-vba tag on your question, here's a vba way of doing it using regular expressions that should satisfy both your primary and secondary issues:

```
Sub tmp()
  Dim regEx As New RegExp
  regEx.Pattern = "^.*?\#?(\d+)"
  Dim i As Integer
  For i = 1 To Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row:
    Set mat = regEx.Execute(Cells(i, 1).Value)
    If mat.Count = 1 Then
      Cells(i, 2).Value = mat(0).SubMatches(0)
    End If
  Next
End Sub
```

The regular expression uses a non-greedy character search (ie the "?" on the end of "'.*?" is what does that) to find the first pattern in the cell that matches either "#123" or just "123" where the "123" is any arbitrary sequence of digits.